# Dynamically change the src of an img element and get width multiple times

Tags: jquery, dynamic, attributes

my name is Ezequiel, I'm new with JQuery

I want to dynamically change the src of an  and get the width of the image that it's displayed.

I have an img tag, with an ID ("idImg").

The problem is that my code works only for the first src change, and I have to change it multiple times (iterative), but I'll show you with only 2 hardcoded changes.

```
      $("#idImg").attr("src", scrString); //src field changes ok
      alert($("#idImg").width()) // ok, this is the real width.
      $("#idImg").attr("src", scrStringANOTHER); //src field changes ok
      alert($("#idImg").width()) // nope, it keeps the same width than the last one.
```

I don't know, just cannot find out what the problem is

**EDIT: I know I have to wait until it loads, but that doesn't work if I change the src multiple times. I need to change the src multiple times, and check the resulting width of each image.**

Any help?

Ty very much

Ezequiel.

Comment: The problem is you didn't give the image time to load.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#idImg").load(function()
{
  alert($(this).width());
});
```

Bind to the load event of the image, at which point the width will be ready.

Another way of going about this is to load the image in a different img then swap it out after load.  See this SO thread on preloading images: [Preloading images with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery)

Comment: Yep, I've tried the load event..
It prints the 1st one, and not the others.

I have to declare it once, right?, it will go there every time I change the src

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#idImg').on('click', function() {
      $(this).attr('src', 'newimage.png');  
    }).load(function() { alert(this.width); });
});
```

See full example: http://jsfiddle.net/k9rn7/

Comment: That works, but the problem is that I need to change the src multiple times and obtain the multiples "widths".

I mean, every time I change the src (I have an array of "src strings"), I want to know the width of that image.

How can I do that?